# hypergeometric distribution of choosing cards to compete a set

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

A certain brand of tea has a picture card in every packet. The cards form a set of 50 different pictures and are distributed among the packets so that any packet purchased is equally likely to contain any one of the cards.

A boy has collected 49 different cards. What is the probability that he will get the remaining picture by opening at most 10 packets?

I realized we should use the hypergeometric distribution here but I couldn't find the parameters.

Define x as the number of packets he opened to get the missing card, and we should calculate P(X<=10)

What is the population size N here since we have infinite packets which could be opened?
What is the number of draws n here? Is it 1 since the boy need 1 missing card?
What's the M here?

Should we need to transform it into a binomial distribution?

Comment: If you are assuming infinitely many packets are available, then the distribution should be geometric not hypergeometric. And the single parameter is $p = 1/50$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @0XLR Thanks so much! I could work out this problem now. But why here we couldn't use hypergeometric distribution? If I take 50 cards as a whole, one of them has the characteristic the boy wanted and the other 49 doesn't have that characteristic. I mean, this classifying make me firstly thinking about hypergeometric instead of geometric.

Comment: @EmitaQQQ Sure you are classifying across two characteristics but that is not the only assumption in a hypergeometric distribution. You also need to be sampling without replacement from some finite population.

Comment: @0XLR I see! It seems I messed up the assumptions of these distributions. Thanks again!

Comment: Not hypergeometric. The probability of opening 10 packets without getting a card of the missing type is  $(49/50)^{10} = 0.8170728.$